# grant usage on particular view in snowflake

Tags: view, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have more than 10+ views in my database(i.e. `myDb`) in snowflake with the role `analyst`.

Now, I have created a new role i.e. `developer` and I want to give

`grant select on view <> to role developer`

permission to one particle view(i.e `test_view`).

How can I grant access to one particular view in snowflake?

Note: consider the schema name `public`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with granting select on view, you also need to grant usage on the database and schema

```
grant usage on database db_name to role developer;
grant usage on schema db_name.public to role developer;
grant select on view db_name.public.my_view to role developer;
```

> Operating on a view also requires the USAGE privilege on the parent
> database and schema

[snowflake-view-privileges](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html#view-privileges)

Answer (score 1):

You do it almost exactly how you have guessed. VIEWs are [schemaObjectPrivileges](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege.html)

```
CREATE ROLE developer;

CREATE VIEW test.test.test_view AS SELECT 1 AS id;

GRANT SELECT ON VIEW test.test.test_view TO ROLE developer;

SHOW GRANTS TO ROLE developer;
```